# how to animate each div once and individually

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of items that return from a backend. Each item forms a kind of tile by means of a `div` and I would like to animate it the very first time it's rendered, as well as individually. The problem is that the items return all together and my render function renders them all together. So a css animation would be visible on every tile at the same time, while what I want is having a "random" bouncing effect for every tile: each tile should appear within 2 seconds, but randomly, not all together.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`velocity.js`](http://velocityjs.org/)'s stagger feature for the task or you write something similar by yourself: create a separate array which will be filled with the elements of such type `{divElement, timeout}`- let's call this array `pairs` (to fill it traverse the original array and assign a timeout within the 0 < 2mins range to every element), and also an empty array, which you're going to use in the render function (not the original one) - `newArray`. After you have your `pairs` array ready, traverse it and call this function on each element:

```
 pairs.forEach(({divElement, timeout})=> {
      setTimeout(()=>{
        newArray.push(divElement)
      }, timeout)
 })
```

and that's it, you render the contents of `newArray` right away (map it to jsx array I suppose) and it eventually gets filled with all the divs that you've had in the beginning.

Comment: To make it random, multiply `timeout` by `Math.random()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class AnimateItemComponent extends React.Component
{
    static propTypes = 
    {
        animate: React.PropTypes.bool
    };

    render()
    {
        let aniamte = this.props.aniamte;
        let style = {};
        let className = ["item-class"];
        let time = parseInt(Math.random() * 2000); // Maximum of 2 seconds

        if (aniamte)
        {
            // Consider support more prefixes 
            style.animationDelay = time + "ms";
        }

        if (this.props.active)
            className.push("animate"); // Class the activate the animation

        return React.createElement("div", {className, style}, "My text");
    }
}

class AnimateComponent extends React.Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.state = {};

        // Initialize the value to keep the prop types boolean
        this.state.aniamte = false;

        // Our items to handle, can be easily replaced with the setState.
        this.state.items = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
    }

    render()
    {
        let content = [];
        let items = this.state.items;
        let aniamte = this.state.aniamte;

        content = items.map(item =>
        {
            return React.createElement(AnimateItemComponent, {animate});
        });

        return content;
    }

    startAnimation()
    {
        this.setState({aniamte: true});
    }

    stopAnimation()
    {
        this.setState({aniamte: false});
    }

    serverRequest()
    {
        // Activate animation:
        this.startAnimation();

        // Stop animation
        this.stopAnimation();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but nope, that's not exactly what I need for two reasons: 1. each render() call would animate them. I want to animate them just when the items return from the backend (therefore "items" is filled). If render() is called again I don't want them animated, but just rendered  2. I want *each* tile animated, but the animation should start randomly among them, or at least that's the visual effect I'd like to give the user (2-3 classes to assign randomly would be more than enough). The tough point is the first one :)

Comment: You'll be very disappointed to know `render` can be called way many times. If you used Redux and placed `console.log` somewhere within `render`, you could see the message 4–5 times on the console by the moment the DOM was completely ready. This is why Ido starts animation in `componentDidMount`, i.e. only one time after corresponding DOM has been rendered.